# Is there any possible way to give an all the services (windows and 3rd party) access to the non admin users?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-services

I am planning to give all the services start /stop access to the users(non-admin) I don't want to give the administrator group access to them.

I have a couple of windows servers running with a couple of third-party services, So just I want to give those services access to my team.

I have tried to create a group policy, but I am not able to give access to all the services, I can only able to give specific windows services only.